# Heading exceeds margins

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, margins

I am writing a document with the `book` class. Hence, the title of the chapter appears at the head of each even page, and the title of the section appears at the head of each odd page. However, some of my titles are too long and the texts exceeds the margins.

How can I resolve this, for instance by ending the heading with '...' if the heading is too long?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=runheadtoobig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide an abbreviated name for those chapters and sections with long titles.

```
\chapter[Short name]{Chapter with a very long name}
```

`\section` etc. also take an optional parameter.

**Edit**
See the link in Ulrike Fischer's comment, which describes an alternate scheme (`\chaptermark` etc).

Comment: I fixed a typo in your answer. I did so because it was a typo in the _code_ and so could have lead to confusion... Hope that's ok.