# Overlapping Page Headers

Tags: header-footer, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chapter title in header too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26234/chapter-title-in-header-too-long)

I'm using LaTeX to write a report, but some of the sections and subsections have long titles, and these titles overlap in the header of the pages. An example code of what I mean is below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Used for header

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy} % makes the header look fancy

\section{this is a very long section}
\subsection{this is a bery long subsection. Going to overlap}

test1

\newpage

test2

\end{document}
```

If you look at the second page of the PDF that is generated the header is overlapping. Is there a way of auto-scaling or manually scaling the header sizes so they don't overlap?

Comment: You're putting too much information in you headers; even scaling them you will get overlaps or unreadable text

Comment: @Mark: In most cases, we can get rid of "LaTeX:" in the question title altogether. This is often the case with questions migrated from [SO].

Comment: @doncherry: That's a good point, but it's useful to differentiate it from, say, ConTeXt in some cases. You're definitely right here though.

Comment: also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/heading-exceeds-margins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @egreg commented, your header text is probably too long, so it's probably worth mentioning the optional argument

```
 \section[short header]{this is a very long section}
```

This puts a short version of the title in the head (and table of contents).

Comment: is there a way of changing only the title in the head, and not in the TOC?